# Bash : Read each line of Localizable.strings

Tags: xcode, bash

In Xcode we have a Localizable.string file we used to support multiple languages in our app. I want to ***spell check*** the Localizable.string file. 
When I use this script the output gets printed to the console

```
cat ~/Desktop/Localizable.strings
```

But when I try to read line by line to spell check using this script a bunch of blank lines are printed to the console.

```
cat ~/Desktop/Localizable.strings | while read line; do
echo $line
done
```

This is how the Localizable.strings file looks like. It has a `key` and a `value`. I only want to check the `Value`

```
"SOME_KEY" = "Spell check this";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not simply `cat ~/Desktop/Localizable.strings`?

Comment: Because the Localizable.string file has a key that is link to a value. The key can be a spelling error, but I want to check the value. Will update my question

Comment: If 1 value why not use grep value file|awk -F"=" '{print $2}'. Also your using tild can u ls the file in your script

Comment: @vahid Because if there's a `=` sign in the key, this will break. Also it will output the value between quotes, and that's probably not what OP wants.

Comment: @vahid: I would not recommend to destroy (with `tr`) *all* the quote characters, since the string itself might contain a `\"`! I would rather just strip the leading and trailing quotes with `sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/";?$//'`, leading to the command: `grep '" *= *"' Localizable.strings | awk '{print $3}' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/";?$//'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a utility which could be used for this. The closest I've found are `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` (but it doesn't enable you to enumerate the keys or the values, only known keys can be printed) and `plutil` by Erica Sadun, but that's compiled for iOS only and isn't opensource.

So it seems you'll need to write a simple utility for this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *fname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:fname];
        for (NSString *value in dict.allValues) {
            printf("%s\n", value.UTF8String);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Invocation: `./<BINARY> Localizable.strings`. This will print all the values of any valid property list file which contains strings only, including `.strings` files.

Answer (score 0):

This will print all values of a specified `Localizable.strings` file

`plutil -p $FILE_PATH | grep '" *=> *"' | while read line; do
      key=$(echo "$line" | sed -E  's/(.*)=>(.*)/\2/')
      echo $key
  done`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 5 version of @user529758's answer:

```
import Foundation

// ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15426631
let path = CommandLine.arguments[1]
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let dict = NSDictionary.init(contentsOf: url)

for value in dict?.allValues ?? [] {
    print(key)
}
```

run via `swift main.swift /path/to/Localizable.strings`